# Can I repair my crew during battle?

Tags: war-thunder

I can rearm at the checkpoint, but can I repair my crew?
I heard  rumors that I can do it, but I haven't found confirmation of this.
Any information is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can repair crew on check point, but your vehicle should has option to repair crew.